# Number of ideals of given norm in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[4]{24}]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Consider the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{24})$. We want to find the number of ideals of norm $100$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ where $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{24}$.

We first notice that the ring of integers is given by $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\alpha^3/4]$. In here we have unique prime ideal factorization. So if we want to find the ideals of norm $100$ in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ we can do it in the following way. First notice that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime divisor of such an ideal $I$, then it also divides $[\mathcal{O}_{K}:I]=100$. And therefore it divides $p=2$ or $p=5$. So we only have to factor $p=2$ and $p=5$ in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ to find all prime ideals above $p=2$ and $p=5$. We find the following factorizations:

$2\mathcal{O}_{K}=(2,\alpha^{3}/4)^4=\mathfrak{p}_{2}^4$ and $5\mathcal{O}_{K}=(5,\alpha^2+2)(5,\alpha^2-2) = \mathfrak{p}_{5}\mathfrak{q}_{5}$.

And the norms are given by $N(\mathfrak{p}_{2})=2$, $N(\mathfrak{p}_{5})=25$ and $N(\mathfrak{q}_{5})=25$. Therefore we find that the only possible ideals of norm $100$ are $\mathfrak{p}_{2}^2\mathfrak{p}_{5}$ and $\mathfrak{p}_{2}^2\mathfrak{q}_{5}$. Since in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ the norm function is multiplicative.

But how does one determine the ideals of norm $100$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$? Since here we have no unique prime ideal factorization and moreover the prime above $2$ is singular. It might be useful to know that $[\mathcal{O}_{K}:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]=8$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Let $\mathcal O$ be the order $\Bbb Z[\alpha]=\Bbb Z\langle1, \alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3\rangle$, it is a subring of the maximal order $\mathcal O_K= \Bbb Z\langle1, \alpha,\frac 12\alpha^2,\frac 14\alpha^3\rangle$. Which is the definition of the **norm** of an ideal $I<\mathcal O$ ? Is it $[\mathcal O:I]$? So we have to find all ideals of $\mathcal O_K$ of absolute norm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_norm#Absolute_norm) $=8\cdot 100$ lying inside $\mathcal O$, i.e. generated by some $\xi\in\mathcal O$?

Comment: So is it always true that when we have an ideal $I$ in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ of norm $8\cdot 100$ that the corresponding ideal $I\cap\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ has norm $100$? I see the otherway around, since when $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ of norm $100$ then $[\mathcal{O}:I]=[\mathcal{O}:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]][\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]:I]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will  use $a$ for $\sqrt[4]{24}$, easier to type.

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathcal O=\Bbb Z[a]=\Bbb Z\langle 1, a, a^2,a^3\rangle$ of norm $100$ in $\mathcal O$, i.e. the quotient
$$R:=\mathcal O/I$$
has cardinality $100$. So the images $\bar 1,\bar a, \bar a^2, \bar a^3$ generate $\Bbb R$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module.

We have than a surjective morphism
$$
\phi:\mathcal O\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(x^4-24)\to R\ ,
$$
parametrized by the image $\bar a\in R$ of $a\in\mathcal O$ (i.e. of $\bar x=x$ modulo $(x^4-24)$). Here $\bar a$ is constrained to, and only to $\bar a^4=24$.

Conversely, each such morphism determines an ideal $I$ of norm $100$.

Which are the possibilities for $R$?

- The ring $R/25$ must have $25$ elements as a group with addition, but cannot have the ring structure $\Bbb Z/25$ or $(\Bbb Z/5)^2$, since there is no $\bar a$ (taken modulo $25$) with $\bar a^4=24=-1$. (Since there is no such element modulo $5$.)
  So $R/25$ is the field $F=\Bbb F_{25}$ with $25$ elements.
  Its unit group is cyclic, $F^\times =\Bbb F_{25}^\times \cong \Bbb Z/24$, generated by some element $u$,
  and there are four elements $\bar a\in F$ with $\bar a^4=24=-1=u^{12}$, explicitly
  $u^3, u^9, u^{15}, u^{21}$. Over $\Bbb F_5$ we have $(x^4-24)=x^4+1=(x^2-2)(x^2+2)$, so we may realize $\Bbb F_{25}=\Bbb F_5[B]/(B^2-2)=\Bbb F_5[b]$, $b^2=2$, and then $\bar a\in\{b, 2b, 3b, 4b\}$.
- The ring $R/4$ has $4$ elements, and from the possibilities $\Bbb Z/4$, $(\Bbb Z/2)^2$, $\Bbb F_4$ only the first one may be realized as surjective image of $\mathcal O/4$, the first one.
- This implies that $20=4\cdot 5$ is in the kernel of any surjective $\phi$.
  We thus consider
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \mathcal O/20
  &=\Bbb Z[x]/(20, x^4-24)
  \\
  &=(\Bbb Z/20)[x]/(x^4-4)
  \\
  &=(\Bbb Z/4)[x]/(x^4-4) \times (\Bbb Z/5)[x]/(x^4-4)
  \\
  &=(\Bbb Z/4)[x]/(x^4) \times \Bbb F_5[x]/((x^2-2)(x^2+2))
  \\
  &=(\Bbb Z/4)[x]/(x^4) 
  \times 
  \Bbb F_5[x]/(x^2-2)
  \times
  \Bbb F_5[x]/(x^2+2)
  \ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  The first factor has two quotients with $4$ elements,

  - one is $(\Bbb Z/4)[x]/(x^4)/(x)=(\Bbb Z/4)[x]/(x)=(\Bbb Z/4)$,
  - the other one is  $(\Bbb Z/4)[x]/(x^4)/(2,x^2)=(\Bbb Z/2)[x]/(x^2)=(\Bbb Z/4)$.
    For the first one, one may use the ideal $(5a)$ at the level of $\mathcal O$ as a quotient.
    For the second one, one may use $(10, 5a^2)$ at the level of $\mathcal O$.

  The last two factors, taken as a whole, as a ring, admit the $4$ morphisms to $\Bbb F_{25}$ mentioned above, two different kernel appear, corresponding to the passage $\Bbb F_5[x]/((x^2-2)(x^2+2))\to\Bbb F_5[x]/((x^2-2)(x^2+2))/(x^2\pm 2)=
  \Bbb F_5[x]/(x^2\pm 2)$, and at the level of $\mathcal O$ we may use the ideal
  $4(a^2\pm 2)$.

We thus obtain four and only four ideals $I_j$ of $\mathcal O$ with $\mathcal O/I_j$ having $100$ elements, $j=1,2,3,4$. They are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_1 &= (20, 5a, 4(a^2+2))\ ,\\
J_2 &= (20, 5a, 4(a^2-2))\ ,\\
J_3 &= (10, 5a^2, 4(a^2+2))\ ,\\
J_4 &= (10, 5a^2, 4(a^2-2))\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

*Notes and comments:*

The following computations are assisted by [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), and we confirm the inputs from the OP, and the above results:

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^4-24)
sage: K
Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^4 - 24
sage: a^4
24

sage: K.class_number()
1

sage: Oa = K.order([a])
sage: Oa.index_in(K.OK())
8

sage: factor(K(2))
(a^3 + 3*a^2 + 4*a + 5) * (1/4*a^3 - 1/2*a^2 + a - 2)^4
sage: factor(K(5))
(1/2*a^2 + 1) * (1/2*a^2 - 1)
sage: (a^3 + 3*a^2 + 4*a + 5).norm()
1
sage: (1/4*a^3 - 1/2*a^2 + a - 2).norm()
-2
sage: (1/2*a^2 + 1).norm()
25
sage: (1/2*a^2 - 1).norm()
25
```

For the four ideals $J_1,J_2,J_3,J_4$ of  $\mathcal O$ explicitly written above, if we are considering the corresponding ideals in $\mathcal O_K$ with the same generators, then it is hard to use the information on the norms from the one order to the other. This highly depends on the intersections...

```
sage: OK = K.OK()
sage: OK
Maximal Order in Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^4 - 24
sage: a^4
24
sage: JOK1 = OK.ideal([20, 5*a, 4*(a^2+2)])
sage: JOK1.is_principal()
True
sage: JOK1.gens_reduced()
(1/2*a^3 + a^2 + a + 2,)
sage: w = 1/2*a^3 + a^2 + a + 2
sage: w.norm()
-200
sage: JOK1.norm()
200
```

and

```
sage: JOK3 = OK.ideal([10, 5*a^2, 4*(a^2+2)])
sage: JOK3.is_principal()
True
sage: JOK3.gens_reduced()
(a^2 + 2,)
sage: 10/(a^2+2)
1/2*a^2 - 1
sage: 5*a^2/(a^2+2)
-1/2*a^2 + 6
sage: (a^2+2).norm()
400
sage: JOK3.norm()
400
```

(A similar functionality is not implemented for non-maximal orders.)